# How to instantiate RealmQuery object in Realm Android [4.2.0]

Tags: java, android, realm

In order to write less code when reading from realm database, I was creating `RealmQuery` objects and then pass them to a static method which could further handle sorting/finding results/copying results to list and closing realm instance like this

```
RealmQuery query = RealmQuery.createQuery(realm, Section.class)
                .equalTo(Section.TENT_ID_FIELD, mVisit.tentID);
```

However, since the recent updates, `RealmQuery.createQuery` is set to package-private, and I couldn't find a public method which returns `RealmQuery`. Is it still possible to create these query objects because it would be really helpful?

Answer (score 2):

OK, just realized it's pretty straightforward, just replace

```
RealmQuery query = RealmQuery.createQuery(realm, Section.class)
                .equalTo(Section.TENT_ID_FIELD, mVisit.tentID);
```

with

```
RealmQuery query = realm.where(Section.class)
                .equalTo(Section.TENT_ID_FIELD, mVisit.tentID);
```